# WMP object in content editor webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a content editor webpart in which I have place a WMP object (windows media player), it plays the video but the annoying part is that it prompts for the Network Password everytime I press play the video.

Let me know Thanks.

Comment: Is the video located outside "same origin"? (different protcol, host or port?)

Comment: it is in the same sharepoint site in its siteassets list

Comment: If you open the video directly, do you still get the prompt? (Could it be some other asset causing it)

Comment: hmmm.. it says it cannot play the mp4 file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the site was not added to the Trusted Sites in the IE.